# ADC on AT91SAM7 with DMA

Tags: arm, dma, keil, adc

I'm trying to write a code for ADC DMA. In my perspective, I've initiated ADC correctly. But it doesn't work and it doesn't interrupt. What am I missing? I initiated ADC and Interrupt and I am willing to access data on the interrupt.
Here is my code:

```
    void __irq ISR_adc(void)
    {
        volatile AT91PS_ADC pADC = AT91C_BASE_ADC;
        unsigned int AdcStatus = AT91C_BASE_ADC->ADC_SR;
        unsigned short* ADC_Ptr;
        unsigned short* ADC_Ptr_Next; 
        printf("ADC is: %d\n",Buffer1[0]);

    if(((AdcStatus & AT91C_ADC_RXBUFF) == AT91C_ADC_RXBUFF) &&
    ((AdcStatus & AT91C_ADC_ENDRX) == AT91C_ADC_ENDRX))
    {//Both bit set when get the end of next buffer

    pADC->ADC_RPR = (unsigned long) Buffer1; // Receive Pointer Register
    pADC->ADC_RCR = AD_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE; // Receive Counter Register
    pADC->ADC_RNPR = (unsigned long)0; // Receive Next Pointer Register
    pADC->ADC_RNCR = 0 ; // Receive Next Counter Registe 

    }
    else if((AdcStatus & AT91C_ADC_ENDRX) == AT91C_ADC_ENDRX)
    {//ENDRX bit set when reach the end of buffer. 
    pADC->ADC_RNCR = AD_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE; 

    }
    *AT91C_AIC_EOICR = 0;  // end of interrupts
}

void Configure_AD(void)
    {
    int i;
    volatile AT91PS_ADC pADC = AT91C_BASE_ADC;     // create a pointer to     USART0 structure
        volatile AT91PS_AIC pAIC = AT91C_BASE_AIC;          // pointer to AIC         data structure
    volatile AT91PS_PIO pPIO = AT91C_BASE_PIOA;         // pointer to PIO data structure

    volatile AT91PS_PMC pPMC = AT91C_BASE_PMC;          // pointer to PMC data structure
#define AD_PRESCAL 1
#define AD_STARTUP 1
#define AD_SHTIM 2
// Enable peripheral clock
pPMC->PMC_PCER = 1 << AT91C_ID_ADC;

//Notice: After ADC_SR = 0xc000 after Reset;
pADC->ADC_CR = AT91C_ADC_SWRST; //Reset AD

//Rxternal trigger: TIOA2 output pulse; Get data using ISP.
pADC->ADC_MR = ((AD_SHTIM << 24) | (AD_STARTUP << 16) | (AD_PRESCAL <<8) | AT91C_ADC_TRGEN_EN | AT91C_ADC_TRGSEL_TIOA2);

pADC->ADC_CHER = AT91C_ADC_CH4; //channel 4 enable

//Configure PDC; Write Counter Register reset ADC_SR.


pADC->ADC_PTCR = AT91C_PDC_RXTDIS ;
pADC->ADC_RPR = (unsigned long)Buffer1; // Receive Pointer Register
pADC->ADC_RCR = AD_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE; // Receive Counter Register
pADC->ADC_RNPR = (unsigned long)0; // Receive Next Pointer Register
pADC-> ADC_RNCR = 0 ; // Receive Next Counter Register
pADC->ADC_PTCR = AT91C_PDC_RXTEN ; //Enable PDC



pADC->ADC_IER = AT91C_ADC_ENDRX | AT91C_ADC_RXBUFF; //enable interrupt on transfer complete



pAIC->AIC_IDCR = (1<<AT91C_ID_ADC);                 
pAIC->AIC_SVR[AT91C_ID_ADC] = (unsigned int)ISR_adc;                
pAIC->AIC_SMR[AT91C_ID_ADC] = (AT91C_AIC_PRIOR_LOWEST | 0x4 );      
pAIC->AIC_IECR = (1<<AT91C_ID_ADC);        

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the global interrupt?